# Python - list index out of range? Twitter Replies

Tags: python, list, twitter, tweepy

I've been working on a script to scrap replies of a single tweet on a log

now, i haven't work on this all by myself, and finally make it almost work but i found a index error almost at the end, a "List index out of range"

i'm a little bit confuse 'cause i don't see what's the problem here... can somebody explain? ._.

```
def tweet_url(t):
    return "https://twitter.com/%s/status/%s" % (t.user.screen_name, t.id)

def get_tweets(filename):
    for line in open(filename):
        yield twitter.Status.NewFromJsonDict(json.loads(line))

def get_replies(tweet):
    user = tweet.user.screen_name
    tweet_id = tweet.id
    max_id = None
    logging.info("looking for replies to: %s" % tweet_url(tweet))
    while True:
        q = urllib.parse.urlencode({"q": "to:%s" % user})
        try:
            replies = t.GetSearch(raw_query=q, since_id=tweet_id, max_id=max_id, count=100)
        except twitter.error.TwitterError as e:
            logging.error("caught twitter api error: %s", e)
            time.sleep(60)
            continue
        for reply in replies:
            logging.info("examining: %s" % tweet_url(reply))
            if reply.in_reply_to_status_id == tweet_id:
                logging.info("found reply: %s" % tweet_url(reply))
                yield reply
                # recursive magic to also get the replies to this reply
                for reply_to_reply in get_replies(reply):
                    yield reply_to_reply
            max_id = reply.id
        if len(replies) != 100:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename="replies.log", level=logging.INFO)
    tweets_file = sys.argv[1] 
    for tweet in get_tweets(tweets_file):
        for reply in get_replies(tweet):
            print(reply.AsJsonString())
```

So... is on the bottom line, the list (sys.argv [1]) is causing the problem here but i don't see why the out of range index error appear, any idea?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the python [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sys.html#sys.argv) -

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).

If I were to read this, I would read till *this* point -

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script

That means, `sys.argv` is a list, and when you try to access something from a list that does not exist in it(by index), it gives you an `IndexError`. You need to call your script with arguments that it needs, and those arguments will be accessed from `sys.argv[1]`

For example -

```
python file_name.py some_argument
```

And `some_argument` will be accessible from `sys.argv[1]`. You could test if arguments have been passed to the script by using `try` or using `len` on argv like -

```
try:
    args = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print('No argument passed')
```

Or -

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    args = sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` refers to command-line arguments passed to your script. When you run the script, `sys.argv[0]` will be the name of your script. `sys.argv[1]` will be the first parameter, `sys.argv[2]` the second, etc. etc. Your script expects `sys.argv[1]` will be a file name to store the results. If this is not provided, the list `sys.argv` will be length one, and the index `[1]` will be out of range. Try running your script with

`script.py output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It expects a command line argument in along with the script.

If you are running it from command line, use this:

```
python script.py tweet_file.txt
```

Where,

*argv[0] is treated as the script name-script.py*

*arg[1] is the tweet file name*

You are missing the tweet file name on execution. From the code I guess it might be some file with tweets in it.